Не резольвятся домены на Alt Linux
Установлен сервер Alt Linux 10.2 на Virtual box 7.0.18. В качестве версии выбрал Debian x64(выбирал просто Linux x64, Redhat и прочие). Сетевой интерфейс "сетевой мост", с таким режимом все другие дистрибутивы раньше работали нормально.
Настроил по статике, прописал ip, шлюз и dns.
[root@host-15 etc]# cat /etc/resolvconf.conf
# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

resolv_conf_head='# Do not edit manually, use\n# /etc/net/ifaces/<interface>/resolv.conf instead.'
resolv_conf=/etc/resolv.conf

# These interfaces will always be processed first.
interface_order='lo lo[0-9]* lo.*'

# These interfaces will be processed next, unless they have a metric.
dynamic_order='tap[0-9]* tun[0-9]* vpn vpn[0-9]* wg[0-9]* ppp[0-9]* ippp[0-9]*'

#Configuration files for named subscriber.
named_zones=/var/lib/bind/etc/resolvconf-zones.conf
named_options=/var/lib/bind/etc/resolvconf-options.conf

#Configuration files for dnsmasq subscriber.
dnsmasq_conf=/etc/dnsmasq.conf.d/60-resolvconf
dnsmasq_resolv=/etc/resolv.conf.dnsmasq
name_servers='77.88.8.7 77.88.8.3'
resolv_conf_options='edns0 trust-ad'

systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-05-19 12:09:21 MSK; 1min 55s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 4403 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 2341)
     Memory: 4.7M
        CPU: 115ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─ 4403 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

мая 19 12:10:25 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 77.88.8.7.
мая 19 12:10:25 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
мая 19 12:10:30 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 77.88.8.3.
мая 19 12:10:35 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 77.88.8.7.
мая 19 12:10:45 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 77.88.8.7.
мая 19 12:10:55 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 77.88.8.7.
мая 19 12:10:55 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 77.88.8.3.
мая 19 12:11:06 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
мая 19 12:11:11 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 77.88.8.7.
мая 19 12:11:11 host-15 systemd-resolved[4403]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 77.88.8.7.
resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 77.88.8.3
        DNS Servers 77.88.8.7 77.88.8.3 8.8.8.8

Link 2 (enp0s3)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 77.88.8.7 8.8.8.8
[root@host-15 network]# cat /etc/systemd/network/alterator-enp0s3.network
[Match]
        Name = enp0s3
[Network]
        IPv6AcceptRA = false
        Address = 192.168.1.55/24
        Gateway = 192.168.1.1
        DNS = 77.88.8.7
        DNS = 8.8.8.8
[DHCPv4]
[root@host-15 network]# ping 77.88.8.7
PING 77.88.8.7 (77.88.8.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 77.88.8.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=31.3 ms
64 bytes from 77.88.8.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=30.7 ms
64 bytes from 77.88.8.7: icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=30.4 ms
[root@host-15 network]# nslookup ya.ru
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


Вообще не работает резольвинг и не пойму в чём проблема. Кто-нибудь подскажите пожалуйста, в чём дело?
Если выставить в настройка Virtual Box тип соединения NAT, а в Alt linux DHCP, то всё работает и интернет появляется, но мне то нужна статика.
